# MS ACCESS SQL Syntax Error in Table Creation

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

Hi I have a simple Table query

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255) 
);
```

I am getting syntax Error in table when I have ran the query. I know the query is correct because I have copied it from W3S . I am using MS ACCESS 2016 and something missing.

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: Ms access has no varchar. Use char instead.

Answer (score 0):

i execute your query in MS ACCESS 2007 , it work properly!
ACCESS  dose not support varchar. try with this query

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName text(255),
    FirstName text(255),
    Address text(255),
    City text(255) 
);
```